# date format in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

guys i am using jqgrid and i have a date that takes its data from json object like this ..

```js
var data = {
      "rows":[
        {"OrderID":"10248","Date":"1996-07-04","time":"16:22","ShipName":"Vins et alcools","CustomerID":"WILMK"},
        {"OrderID":"10249","Date":"1996-07-05","time":"17:00","ShipName":"Toms Spezialit\u00e4ten","CustomerID":"TRADH"},
        {"OrderID":"10250","Date":"1996-07-08","time":"17:09","ShipName":"Hanari Carnes","CustomerID":"HANAR"},
       ]}
```

and i defining it like this in jsp file

```
     { label: 'Date', name: 'Date', width: 150 ,
                           editable: true,
                           edittype:"text",
                           editoptions: {
                               autoclose: true,
                               autoOpen: false,
                                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                orientation : 'auto bottom',
                               dataInit : function (elem) {
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       $(elem).datepicker({ showOn: 'focus' });
                                   },10);
                               },
                           },
                       },
```

so for example the date is `1996-07-04` and when i edit it it gives me `05/30/1904` .. any help ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have formatter= "date" in the column model with out that any format you specify in the grid is meaningless. the reason it works on non edit is because it assumes it as a string and it is putting it there as is from the json.

The the fix will be

Add formatter and formatoptions to the column model and dateFormat to the date picker as as follows

```
{ label: 'Date',
       name: 'Date',
       width: 150 , 
       editable: true, 
       edittype:"text",

      // add the two lines below                
      formatter: "date",
      formatoptions: {  newformat: "yyyy-mm-dd" },

      editoptions: {
       autoclose: true,
      autoOpen: false,
     // format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', Commented it no need
      orientation : 'auto bottom',
      dataInit : function (elem) {
      setTimeout(function(){
      $(elem).datepicker({ showOn: 'focus',
            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'    });
          },10);},    },
               },
```